# If light from a moving emitter has doppler effect would a laser used on Earth show that?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, kinematics, earth, doppler-effect

If light from a moving emitter has doppler effect would a laser used on Earth show that? Will the laser have 2 different frequencies when pointed in 2 opposite directions on Earth due to Earth's intrinsic motion?

Answer (score 1):

Doppler effect depends on the *relative* motion of the observer to the emitter. If the observers you are considering are at rest with respect o the earth frame, then they will observe no effect and measure the same frequency. However if they are for example out in space, such that the earth is moving away from one and towards the other, then they will see a different frequency.